# CSS Margin and Padding don't work on IMG elements unless they are display:block

Tags: html, css

Why does padding and margin work on block img, but not on inline.

I am having a layout problem with my images in CSS.  I want no pixels (no margin, no padding) between each image, and I want a row of 4 images.

The only way padding or margin (setting to 0) works is if I use display:block as part of the style for the image.  As soon, as I use inline, there are several pixels between each image and the padding and margin is ignored.

Anyway that I can get my own paddings and margins in images that are inline?

Answer (score 0):

I've found wrapping all `img` to `div` as a really useful practice.

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
```

It is userful for adding any additional actions with images.
For example, you want to crop all of them to fit 400x200 block. You just do:

```
<style>
    .-crop {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .-crop img {
        min-width: inherit;
        min-height: inherit;
    }
    .image {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        min-width: 400px;
        min-height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="image -crop">
    <img src="/path/to/image1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image -crop">
    <img src="/path/to/image2.jpg">
</div>
```

When images are wrapped, it is easier to solve some tasks. You need to make images bigger on hover? They are wrapped, you change `img` size, but not `div`, so your layout is ok. You need images to slide up with 20px on click? Same strory. You want them to be in center of some 400x200 area? They are wrapped, add `vertical-align` and `text-align` to `div`.

Of course, in common cases just `img` is fine. But when suddenly you have to add some additional actions -- you need to wrap them. So i wrap them everytime even if there is no need at the moment. Just for future.

Comment: You should explain why this is useful practice.  I've been doing this for more than 10 years and don't see any universal benefit (outside of a specific application required).

Answer (score 0):

So you want an image to display inline, but act as a block?

Have you tried `display: inline-block;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: block` and `float:left` if you want to have more images in one row.